# Suppose $h:M \rightarrow E$ is a homeomorphism onto its image . Show that $h(M)$ is a $G_{\delta}$-set.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, borel-sets

Let $M$ and $E$ be complete metric spaces. 
    Suppose $h:M \rightarrow E$ is a homeomorphism onto its image (i.e. $h$ is a continuous one-to-one map, and $h^{-1}|_{h(M)}$ is continuous). 
    Show that $h(M)$ is a $G_{\delta}$-set.

My attempt: I think it has something to do with 
$$h(M) = \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}h(?)$$
where $?$ is open in $E.$

However, I do not know what precisly is $?$.

Comment: How about a $\delta$-neighborhood of $h(M)$ for $\delta=\frac{1}{n}$?  (This open set is given by $\bigcup_{x\in h(M)}\,B^E_\delta(x)$, where $B^E_\delta(x)$ is the open ball in $E$ centered at $x$ with radius $\delta$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B_E = \{ e \in E: \| e \| \leq 1 \}$ be the unit ball centered at $e$ with radius $1.$

Let $(\varepsilon_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers such that $\varepsilon_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty.$
We claim that 
$$h(M) = \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\bigcup_{y \in h(M)}(y+ \varepsilon_n \cdot B_E).$$
For each $n \in \mathbb{N},$ clearly we have $h(M) \subseteq \cup_{y \in h(M)}(y + \varepsilon_n \cdot B_E).$
Therefore, $h(M) \subseteq \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\bigcup_{y \in h(M)}(y+ \varepsilon_n \cdot B_E).$

I constructed the following proof based on Batominovski's comment.

To show another inclusion, we let $z \in \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\bigcup_{y \in h(M)}(y+ \varepsilon_n \cdot B_E).$
By definition, for each $n \in \mathbb{N},$ there exists $y \in h(M)$ such that $z \in y+\varepsilon_n \cdot B_E.$
Therefore, as $n \rightarrow \infty,$ there exists $y \in h(M)$ such that $z = y \in h(M).$
Hence, the reverse inclusion holds.

Since $\bigcup_{y \in h(M)}(y+ \varepsilon_n \cdot B_E)$ is open in $E,$ we conclude that $h(M)$ is a $G_{\delta}$-set.